# With Xmonad / GNOME, switch gnome-panel between monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gnome-panel, xmonad

I'm using gnome with Xmonad as my window manager on Ubuntu 11.10. When I use a external monitor with my laptop, extending the desktop with either nvidia-settings or disper, the gnome-panels (Top bar and running applications/workspaces bar) seem to display on either monitor randomly. How can I either force them to use one monitor or change their position with a scriptable command that I can hot-key?

Here are things that don't work:

- I can move them by right click->Properties-> Uncheck "expand" -> Alt-drag, etc. This works, but requires way too much mouse-work every time I plug in my external monitor.
- Using gconf-editor to change any of the gnome-panel settings doesn't actually change anything: `gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0/orientation top` The `/monitor "1"` setting also doesn't change anything

[edit]
gpoo's solution is almost correct - just use dconf instead of gsettings.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/toplevels/bottom-panel/monitor 1
```

gsettings doesn't let me change the required keys, though it's likely I just can't understand its cryptic and undocumented syntax. All of `dconf`, `dconf-editor`, and `gsettings` need man pages. (gsettings's man page does nothing to explain what the terms mean.)

Comment: If you like xmonad, you might also like xmobar, which can be forced to a particular monitor with the "-x" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try gsettings or dconf.  You might want to change `org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout.toplevels.top-panel.monitor` and `org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout.toplevels.top-panel.orientation`.

It would be something like:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout.toplevels.top-panel.orientation top
$ gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout.toplevels.top-panel.monitor 1
```

Comment: While gsettings doesn't work, dconf does: `dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-panel/layout/toplevels/bottom-panel/monitor 0` moves the bottom-panel to the first monitor, and `.../monitor 1` to the second.

gsettings didn't work for me, since it claims these keys and dirs (or whatever "schema" are) don't exist:
`$ gsettings list-keys org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout
object-id-list
toplevel-id-list`
`$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout
org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout object-id-list ['menu-bar',...]
org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout toplevel-id-list ['top-panel', 'bottom-panel']`